# what is the effect of print function in sapply?

Tags: r

```
data <-c("001","002","103","119","129")
n1<- sapply(data,function(x){
    x<-gsub(pattern="(\\d+)(\\d\\d)$","\\2",x)
    if(gsub("(\\d)(\\d)","\\1",x)=="0")
         x <- gsub("(\\d)(\\d)","\\2",x)
     },USE.NAMES=FALSE)

n2<- sapply(data,function(x){
    x<-gsub(pattern="(\\d+)(\\d\\d)$","\\2",x)
    if(gsub("(\\d)(\\d)","\\1",x)=="0")
         x <- gsub("(\\d)(\\d)","\\2",x)
     print(x)},USE.NAMES=FALSE)
```

Why n2 can get a vector of  "1"  "2"  "3"  "19" "29" ,n1 can not?n2 is more one line `print(x)` than n1,what is the effect of print function here?

Comment: When the `if` clause is false, the last thing executed in the function is the test, which returns NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here exactly is a little easier to spot when we apply some better indentation and add some spaces:

```
n2 <- sapply(data, function(x) {
    x <- gsub(pattern = "(\\d+)(\\d\\d)$", "\\2", x)
    if (gsub("(\\d)(\\d)", "\\1", x) == "0") x <- gsub("(\\d)(\\d)", "\\2", x)
    print(x)
}, USE.NAMES=FALSE)
```

If you do not use an explicit `return` statement, R will return the outcome of the last operation. In the first case, when the `if` statement fails, the last `x <-` will be skipped, and `NULL` will be returned. Adding `print(x)` both prints the number to the screen, and causes it to be returned from the function. This explains that the second case does always have a valid (non-`NULL`) return value.

In stead of `print(x)`, I would use `return(x)`, or simply `x`.